# Unicode characters encoding for a MySQL output

Tags: php, mysql, unicode

I'm trying to retrieve data from a table whose collation is 'utf8_general_ci' and the column titled 'app_name' has string like : Plants vs. Zombies™ 2,포코팡 for Kakao,네이버 - Naver,µTorrent® - Torrent App. When I tried to query the table as below:

```
   <?php

   $con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root') or die('Error connecting to server');

   mysql_select_db('googleappanalysis', $con); 

  if(isset($_POST['appType']))
  {
    $appType = $_POST['appType'];
    $month = $_POST['month'];
    $year = $_POST['year'];
  }


  $monthYear = $month.$year; 

  mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8")

  if($appType == "Apps with IA" ){
    $sql="SELECT app_name  FROM MonthlyAppState WHERE is86 = 1 AND is86 IS NOT NULL AND monthYear = '".$monthYear."'";

    $result=mysql_query($sql);
   }elseif($appType == "Apps with no IA" ){
    $sql="SELECT app_name  FROM MonthlyAppState WHERE is86 = 0 AND is86 IS NOT NULL AND monthYear = '".$monthYear."'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
   }


    $table = array();
    $table['cols'] = array(
array('label' => $appType, 'type' => 'string')
 );


 $rows = array();
 $appendingString = "";
 while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

    $temp = array();
$temp[] = array('v' => (string)$r['app_name']);
$rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
    $appendingString = $appendingString."/".$r['app_name'];
 }

 $myFile = "logfile.txt";  
 $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file"); 
 fwrite($fh, $appendingString);
 fclose($fh);

 $table['rows'] = $rows;

 // encode the table as JSON
 $jsonTable = json_encode($table);

  // set up header; first two prevent IE from caching queries
 header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
 header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
 header('Content-type: application/json');

 echo $jsonTable;
 ?>
```

The jsontable throws null values and for the file 'logfile.txt'the unicode characters is converted to '???' as seen [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/enxchfkwqlc74hc/logfile.txt?n=3619514)

Comment: You should really avoid using mysql and instead use something like mysqli or pdo. It makes protecting yourself from sql injection trivial whereas the regular mysql class the burden of sanitizing your queries always falls on you rather than your technology.

Comment: What is the character set (not collation) of a column you're selecting from?

Comment: its utf8 for app_name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8', $con);
```

right after `mysql_connect` to set your client character set.

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php

Comment: You're advocating using a deprecated function?

Comment: @Phil: assuming it might be 10Mb of code - I don't see how rewriting all of it is better than adding a **single** line. Especially if OP doesn't intend to upgrade their php in a near future

Comment: He's also got a `SET NAMES utf8` query

Comment: `mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8');` is the non-deprecated version